# Sitecore domains and roles

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I want to add couple Sitecore domains and roles and have an ability to store these settings in our solution to share with other teammates. We use TDS to save Sitecore items into our solution usually, but I don't know how to save domains and roles.
Just for test: I added a domain and a role for that domain. I found that new role in the usual membership table in Core DB and a new domain in the special config file ..\Website\App_Config\Security\Domains.config.

I can see only one way at the moment: use this config file to share with other teammates(or create some patch file) and use serialize/deserialize feature for Roles(..\Data\serialization\security\sitecore\Roles).

Does somebody know any other way to solve this task? it might be that Sitecore stores Roles as usual Sitecore items somewhere in Code DB as well, however I didn't mange to find this folder in the tree.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config solution for domains is correct.

For roles, TDS does support the ability to sync them since version 5.1. You must enable this in the project properties under the `General` tab first. This adds a new node under your TDS project called `Sitecore Roles` that produces a different context menu with a `Sync Sitecore Roles` option.

Comment: Thank you. We found this ability, but It should be enabled in General settings of the TDS project first of all.

Comment: Good clarification. I edited my response to reflect the complete answer.

Comment: Is there any similar option for adding sitecore users?

Comment: Negative. There is no TDS option for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sitecore packages to move security accounts. In Sitecore package, you have the option to add security accounts. You can refer to this article about moving the Sitecore users and roles. http://sitecorejourney.nileshthakkar.in/2014/07/how-to-create-package-of-sitecore-users.html

But remember you need to migrate passwords after installing the package. As all of the transferred users will have their passwords set either to a random value (when using Sitecore packages), or to the default value "b" (when using serialization). Please refer to https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/242631 for transferring passwords.

Comment: Thank you for possible solution, but I would prefer to use TDS.